# How to build libraries depend on each other in CMakeList

Tags: cmake

In the root directory of a project, there are two libraries folder, one is lib1 and the other is lib2.

In lib1 folder, there are files like:

```
lib1Config.cmake.in + lib1ConfigVersion.cmake.in + CMakeList.txt
```

In lib2 folder, there are files like:

```
lib2Config.cmake.in + lib2ConfigVersion.cmake.in + CMakeList.txt
```

AND in lib2, the CMakeList.txt contains a FIND_PACKAGE(lib1 REQUIRED). when I try to run the cmake in the root directory, which just simply call add_subdirectory(lib1) and add_subdirectory(lib2), the CMakeList.txt in lib2 complains that it can not find lib1Config.cmake. Then, my question is: how can i make proper adjustments to make it work.

FYI: here, lib1 is actually [osgworks](https://github.com/mccdo/osgworks/tree/master) and lib2 is [osgbullet](https://github.com/mccdo/osgbullet/tree/master). I am trying to include them in my project's lib folder. Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here that osgBullet tries to use `find_package` on osgWorks but osgWorks is not yet built and installed the time osgBullet is configured.

This could be fixed with something along these lines (in osgBullet and in your project)

```
if(NOT TARGET <some-osgWorks-target)
    find_package(osgWorks REQUIRED)
endif()
...
if(TARGET <some-osgWorks-target)
    target_link_libraries(<my-project> <osgWorks-targets>...)
else()
    target_link_libraries(<my-project> ${OSGWORKS_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

But I would say, it's better not to include **osgworks** and **osgbullet** in your project at all. They are external dependencies, prerequisites. Let your project's CMakeLists.txt (and the generated the IDE or text-editor projects) contain only the targets you are currently working on.

You need to build and install **osgworks** and **osgbullet** before configuring your project. This can be done manually or you can write a small shell script for that. A possible implementation:

```
cmake -H<osgWorks-source> -Bb/osgworks -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/install \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<other-deps-install-dirs>
cmake --build b/osgworks --target install
cmake -H<osgBullet-source> -Bb/osgbullet -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/install \
    "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$PWD/install;<other-deps-install-dirs>"
cmake --build b/osgbullet --target install
```

If you're using Visual Studio or Xcode, you need to set the config with `--config Release` in the `cmake --build` line instead of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`.

After that you can configure your own project:

```
cmake -H<my-source> -Bb -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/install \
    "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$PWD/install;<other-deps-install-dirs>"
```

Comment: So, what kind of libraries should I put into the project's lib folder. I do not know the differences here.

Comment: by <some-osgWorks-target, what do you mean ?

Comment: Reading the config module I think osgWorks creates these targets: osgwTools, osgwQuery, osgwMx and osgwControls. So any of these can be used to check whether osgWorks is added with `add_subdirectory`